# How to measure database performance?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, firebug

I'm developing a web app that will access and work with large amounts of data in a MySQL database, something like a dictionary/thesaurus. I need to test the performance of the DB as its size increases, so I know how slow each request will be in the future.

Any ideas? Like are there specific tools to check DB performance for a particular query, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Maatkit](http://www.maatkit.org/)'s [query profiler](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-query-profiler.html) to measure impact of data amount on MySQL performances.

And [generatedata.com](http://www.generatedata.com/) to generate the data you need to test your app.

You can also test your application responsiveness using HTTP testing tools like :

- Apache's bundled 'ab' tool (Apache Bench)
- [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)
- [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: I don't see anything that could prevent people using JMeter on localhost.

Comment: Seems like the definitive answer until we hear of better methods.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know what, specifically you're testing? Measuring "performance" is almsot always useless, unless you know exactly what it is you want.

For example, are you looking for low latency on query result retrieval? Perhaps high throughput on date retrieval? Perhaps you care more about fast insertions into the database, and less about fast query results? Perhaps you care about different things on different tables (in fact, that's almost always the case).

My advice will probably be ignored, but I'll say it anyway:

**Don't** optimise before you know what you want.

**Don't** optimise as you write the code.

When you do get around to optimising your database, make sure you optimise for the right things. Use realistic data - if you're testing dictionary-sized hunks of text, don't test with binary data (for example).

Anyway, I realise you were probably looking for a more technical answer, but hey...

Comment: Helpful anyways... and as I said before, "so I know how slow each request will be in the future"

Comment: but again - what does "slow" mean in this context? Are you measuring latency or throughput? 

Anyway, good luck with the testing!

Comment: Latency in terms of how long it takes to execute all the queries required to generate a dynamic webpage? I'm basically talking about heavy visitor load on a DB server ... and how much total time each webpage will take to be *generated*

Comment: I started off with the assumption that MySQL will be the bottleneck, which is why I'm not worried about measuring the PHP part.

Answer (score 1):

a good tool to use is apache's ab, which comes standard with apache httpd server. this tool can make multiple connections to a web server and benchmark its performance. while firebug is a good way to see in what order things lod, how long each item takes to load, etc., you're only seeing one user's experience. against an unloaded test server, that information can only take you so far. ab simulate multiple users connecting and will give a more realistic picture of how a particular page handles concurrent users.

which leads to me a limitation in ab: it only tests one URL. i get around this often by whipping up a simple test webpage that makes a random selection from a list of pre-defined URL's that i want to test. for example: the login page, a search result, posting a comment, and so on. ab hits the test page, and the test page simply calls one of the test URL's (possibly with a randomized paramter) and returns that page. in this manner, you get a better idea of how your whole site handles concurrent users.

PS: your OS is unanswerable. you'll have to figure that out yourself based on how your application is written, the layout of your data, the configuraiton of the web server and the database server, etc.